# Sumar fechas con formato año-mes-dia en Javascript o Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, date

Necesito saber como sumar fechas con Js por ejemplo si tengo la fecha 2019-06-10 que quede 2019-06-11. Pero necesito que sea en formato de fecha para que cuando llegue a 2019-06-30 y se le sume un día de como resultado 2019-07-01 osea el mes siguiente.

> Por cierto la variable con la fecha en el formato ya la tengo osea no tengo que consultar la fecha, ya yo tengo esta variable.

`var fecha = '2019-06-10' //fecha tomada de un input automáticamente`

solo tendría que sumarle un día a esa fecha tomada automáticamente... Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es convertir el `string` que tienes a fecha usando `new Date`, luego seteas la fecha obteniendo el día y le sumas 1.

```js
var fechaString = '2019-06-10';
var fecha = new Date(fechaString);

for(var i = 0; i < 21; i++){
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1);
  
  console.log(fecha);
}
```

En el ejemplo utilizo un ciclo `for` para que veas como aumenta el día y posteriormente el mes de la fecha.

Comment: Perfecto @BenderPaisa .... Muchas gracias :D agradecido

Comment: Otra pregunta @BenderPaisa, si yo quisiera solo mostrar los dias sumados en vez de toda la fecha como se podria hacer ?

Comment: @MaikerLeon a que te refieres con "solo los dias sumados" osea no quieres tener ni año ni mes ni horas?

Comment: Exacto en el caso en que quisiera solo imprimir los dias por ejemplo 29 30 31 01 02 03, es porque tengo que hacer ambas cosas y deseo saber, y la verdad me has ayudado bastante

Comment: Podrías usar `fecha.getDate()` para capturar únicamente el día de la fecha, y claro es un placer ayudarte siempre que necesites ayuda y yo sepa la solución te voy a ayudar